# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows: change default window size/location

Tags: windows-10, bash

I'm honestly surprised I haven't seen this question asked anywhere before, because it drives me crazy.

It used to be that when I opened Bash from my Taskbar shortcut, it would open nearly maximized, but with the bottom 25 pixels below the taskbar, which was annoying. Or I could open it from a search or its shortcut within explorer, and it would always open a small window.

I re-made my taskbar shortcut, but now Bash only opens at a specific small size on a specific position and only ever on Monitor 1. Unlike virtually every other program which will open wherever it was last closed.

Is there a way to get Bash to remember size and position, or change the default size position?

Comment: In the short-cut's Properties, the **Layout** tab allows you to set the row count, column count and position (make sure that **Let system position window** is not checked) and the **Font** tab sets the character size.

Comment: @AFH sadly there is no Layout tab for Bash because it's a Windows App...

Comment: @BrianLeishman - It is a Windows console application, and there are 4 tabs: `Options`, `Font`, `Layout` and `Colours`.

Comment: @AFH I think it might have used to be like that, but after this fresh Windows install a few weeks ago, it installed through the Windows store only, and it's called "Ubuntu 18.04" now. There's an option called "App Settings" when right clicked, but that takes me to a Windows 10-esque settings screen that never actually loads

Comment: @BrianLeishman - I'm on Win10/1803, and it works as I described. This was the latest release at the time the question was logged. I've not been in a hurry to move to 1809, and I'm even less motivated to do so now. I normally use native Ubuntu 18.04, and this works well.

Comment: @AFH Yeah I'm on 1809, it's *almost* worth it just for the dark explorer though